# how can i redirect all files in one directory to another directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've moved the files on my server to a new directory and would like to 301 redirect all the requests to the files in the new directory.

Say I have:

- domain.com/test/apples.php
- domain.com/test/oranges.php
- domain.com/test/bananas.php

How do I redirect them to:

- domain.com/apples.php
- domain.com/oranges.php
- domain.com/bananas.php

without having to redirect each one individually?

Comment: Do you have to use 301 ? You might also use mod_rewrite with regex.
Something you might need: http://superuser.com/questions/155139/htaccess-301-redirect-with-regular-expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using a server with mod_rewrite, In your root create a file named ".htaccess" and insert the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that this will rewrite every single file in the test directory to the domain you inserted.

If you only want to redirect .php files use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*).php http://domain.com/$1.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**NOTES:**
Don't forget to change the domain.com to your domain name, also this type of redirect will make a [301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) that is usefull for redirecting PERMANENTLY the url of a file (**This will help search engines updating your links**).