# htaccess, redirect all folder traffic to a single file inside

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this situation:

http://www.site.asd/folder

Inside FOLDER I have one file getting content from other folder outside of it.

I need to get all traffic like "http://www.site.asd/folder/data1/data2/data3/data4.ext" and get this call "http://www.site.asd/folder/file.php?d1=data1&d2=data2&d3=data3&d4=data4.ext" without changing URL

This is what I made... and isn't working... :'(

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /folder/file.php?d1=$1&d2=$2&d3=$3&d4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Any advice/solution to make this work?

Thanks to all!

Comment: you can have a look at these  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183022/how-can-i-redirect-all-files-in-one-directory-to-another-directory  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975904/htaccess-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-one-page-410-gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove leading slash from your matching pattern. As `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /folder/file.php?d1=$1&d2=$2&d3=$3&d4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure this rule is in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

It might work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /folder/file.php?d1=$1&d2=$2&d3=$3&d4=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but is giving "server error".

Comment: nop, now is working (no error), but is ignoring the rule or something like that... return a 404 page...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$/folder/file.php?d1=$1&d2=$2&d3=$3&d4=$4 [QSA,L]
```

this should work, just point the rewriteBase to the folder you want